# Random loss of 2 rep

Tags: support, reputation

I have just lost 2 rep and nothing is showing up on my reputation tab. Has this happened to anyone else? Why has this happened? It's really strange and annoying, since I have spent all day trying to raise it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the "show removed posts" checkbox at the bottom of the Reputation tab in your profile and you should see it.

Comment: Thank you! It was from a post that I edited which was then removed.

Comment: ...is there any reason "show removed posts" is even an option rather than the default (with no option)?

Comment: @BenBrocka To avoid drawing attention to removed posts, far as I know.